# How to design a crystal report to fit the data in a Letter head template

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a letter head which is supposed to print the data comes from the crystal report. Once the letter head inserted to the printer & generate and print the crystal report, the data should fit to the letter head fields.

eg: assume letter head has a field called Company Name, so i should design the crystal report field to fit the data align with the template fields. Like Company Name: ABC Company

Is there any proper way of designing the crystal report to cater this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can physically measure the distance from the top and left of the page for your starting positions (remember that Crystal itself adds a margin, so 1" in the designer is 1" plus the margin size on paper).  You will almost certainly have to tweak it too.

Comment: mmmmm yaa..that's how i'm currently doing that. So i'm looking for some idle solution. like if we can insert the whole template as the background image of the report, it will be easy to set the data aligned with those fields. Thanks for your idea!...

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  Do you have the template, or the top of the template, saved as an image?  You can add an image and put things of top of it, as long as it is all in one section. Add the image to a section like the page header, right-click it, select "Move", and then select "To Back".  Then you can put the fields on top of the image.

Comment: Yeap.. I need to crop the template sections to fit the report. So how do i crop the template to fit to the correct with and height of crystal report sections. because template zoom level and crystal report zoom level is differ. otherwise i hv to re-size the template cropped sections to fit into the crystal report.

Comment: Either change the Crystal margins to 0, or crop it to a set size and use that size as the Crystal margins.  For something like this where the size of the margins matters, you will want to have them set manually, otherwise Crystal may change the margins based on the printer being used.